# Obtener algun tipo de identificador de un dispositivo movil con Ionic, ngCordova?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ng-cordova

Necesito obtener un ID o algun tipo de indentificador unico de un dispositivo movil donde instale mi APP, si alguien sabe como hacer esto agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, hay varias maneras:

- El imei= El único problema es que solo permite en android ya que en ios no hay permiso de acceder.
- La mac= El problema sería en ios 8 que asigna una mac aleatoria.
- El uuid= es un identificador único universal de 16 bytes. Es el que te recomiendo, es compatible con android, ios y todas las plataformas.
  Primero necesitas instalar el plugin de cordova

```html
sudo cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

y luego utilizarlo para obtener el id

```html
$ionicPlatform.ready(function {
  console.log(ionic.Platform.device());
});
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos. 
Pd: ten en cuenta que si ejecutas ionic serve no podrás obtener éste identificador, asegurate de realizar las pruebas con dispositivos físicos

Comment: gracias, hare las prueba correspondientes,espero funcione

Comment: me entrego un objeto, pero no se como obtener ese idetificador que dices

Answer (score 0):

El único problema es que uuid cambia una vez desintalar  y vuelves a instalar, yo hasta el momento no he encontrado alguna forma de generar un uuid único.
saludos